# MySQL select the first row of a table

Tags: mysql, date

I know there are dozens of "select the first row" questions, but I have an interesting situation that I don't think I can fix with a LIMIT.

I'm trying to show properties that are available between a start and end date, with N days consecutively available.  I'm so close.

I'm going to break this query apart into bits because it's a big one.

## Blocked Dates (part 1)

```
(SELECT c.id,c.property_id,c.start_date,c.end_date FROM property_calendar as c WHERE c.start_date <= '.$endQuote.' AND c.end_date >= '.$startQuote)
UNION
(SELECT l.id,l.property_id,l.start_date,l.end_date FROM lease as l WHERE l.start_date <= '.$endQuote.' AND l.end_date >= '.$startQuote.' AND l.status < 6)
ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

This union smashes our two calendars together for easy comparison.  Each entry has a start_date and end_date.  Dates that fall between (including the start and end) are considered to be unavailable.

## The Calculator (part 2)

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATEDIFF( IFNULL(ct2.start_date, '2015-12-09'), ct1.end_date) - 1, 0) as open_days,
(DATEDIFF(ct1.start_date, '2015-12-01') - 1) as first_open,
IFNULL(DATEDIFF( LEAST(ct1.end_date, '2015-12-09'), GREATEST(ct1.start_date, '2015-12-01' ) ) + 1, 0)  as blocked_days,
ct1.property_id as property_id
FROM ({blocked dates}) as ct1
LEFT JOIN ({blocked dates}) as ct2 ON ct2.property_id = ct1.property_id AND ct2.start_date > ct1.end_date
GROUP BY ct1.property_id,ct1.start_date
```

This takes the table in part 1, and joins it to itself allowing us to compare the previous blocked date with the next.  `open_days` is the negative space between each blocked date.  `blocked_days` is just how many days are blocked in `ct1`.  The part that's causing trouble is `first_open`.

This query works, unless the first blocked date occurs after the start date the user gave.  In that case, we miss out on counting those first few days that are open.  So, part of my solution was to add the `first_open` which just simply calculates `DATEDIFF( ct1.start_date, {the given start date})`.

## The Final Sum

```
SELECT cj.property_id, 
IFNULL(SUM(cj.blocked_days), 0) as total_blocked,
IFNULL(GREATEST(MAX(cj.open_days), MAX(cj.first_open)), 0) as consec_days_avail
FROM {the calculator} as cj
```

As I said, here is where I have the problem.  Selecting `MAX(cj.first_open)` obviously won't work for me.  There's no unique ID either I can go by because the availability is the combination of two tables where the IDs can possibly collide.  And MySQL doesn't have a `FIRST()` function to use.  But basically I only care about the greatest available consecutive days because we just don't care where the consecutive days occur, just that they happen between the user's start and end dates.

So is there a better way to structure this query?  I've tried exploring methods to get only the first row in The Calculator to actually `DATEDIFF()` and all others are 0, but the problem I had using `IF(ct1.start_date = MIN(ct1.start_date), DATEDIFF(...), 0)` was that the first two rows would have a non 0 value and I only want just the first.  And I think that has something to do with how I'm joining a table on itself.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

## Edit

For the curious parties here's the query all in one piece.  This is now working (as far as I can tell) as intended.  Now I'm just wondering if there's a better way or if there's any tips.

```
SELECT p.* as id, IFNULL(cd.total_blocked, 0) as total_blocked, IFNULL(cd.consec_days_avail, 0) as consec_days_avail
FROM properties AS p
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT cj.property_id, IFNULL(SUM(cj.blocked_days), 0) as total_blocked, IFNULL(GREATEST(MAX(cj.open_days), MAX(cj.first_open)), 0) as consec_days_avail
FROM (
SELECT IFNULL(DATEDIFF( IFNULL(ct2.start_date2, {user_end_date}), ct1.end_date) - 1, 0) as open_days,IF( MIN(ct1.start_date) = ct1.start_date,  DATEDIFF(ct1.start_date, {user_start_date}), 0) as first_open,IFNULL(DATEDIFF( LEAST(ct1.end_date, {user_end_date}), GREATEST(ct1.start_date, {user_start_date} ) ) + 1, 0)  as blocked_days,ct1.property_id as property_id
FROM ((SELECT c.id,c.property_id,c.start_date,c.end_date FROM property_calendar as c WHERE c.start_date <= {user_end_date} AND c.end_date >= {user_start_date}) UNION (SELECT l.id,l.property_id,l.start_date,l.end_date FROM lease as l WHERE l.start_date <= {user_end_date} AND l.end_date >= {user_start_date} AND l.status < 6) ORDER BY start_date ASC) as ct1
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT c.id as id2,c.property_id as property_id2,c.start_date as start_date2,c.end_date as end_date2 FROM property_calendar as c WHERE c.start_date <= {user_end_date} AND c.end_date >= {user_start_date}) UNION (SELECT l.id,l.property_id,l.start_date,l.end_date FROM lease as l WHERE l.start_date <= {user_end_date} AND l.end_date >= {user_start_date} AND l.status < 6) ORDER BY start_date2 ASC) as ct2 ON ct2.property_id2 = ct1.property_id AND ct2.start_date2 > ct1.end_date
GROUP BY ct1.property_id,ct1.start_date) as cj
GROUP BY cj.property_id) as cd on cd.property_id = p.id
WHERE p.state = 1
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING total_blocked < DATEDIFF({user_end_date},{user_start_date}) + 1 AND ( consec_days_avail >= {user_days_avail} OR total_blocked = 0 )
ORDER BY p.id asc
```

Comment: I'd rather just some data and a desired result - tho at least this shows you're trying

Comment: @Strawberry I get ya.  Sorry been working on this for days and I figured it would be an easier read broken apart.  I'll put together a fiddle in a bit and update.

Comment: Just a tidbit.  `MIN(datestamp)` and `MAX(datestamp)` work fine as aggregate functions, returning the first and last datestamp.  Also, you may be misusing the nasty nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`, which can drive you berserk. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @OllieJones Right, but because of the join we end up with a table with two columns that are both labeled `start_date` so weird things happen.  But you just gave me an idea.

Comment: Use aliases to make your subquery column names unique.

Comment: @OllieJones I think I'll give that a try.  I've been using the same UNION in both the FROM and JOIN of the calculator but I haven't tried making a slightly different UNION statement for the join.

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks, that worked.  I can't believe I didn't think of something so simple like that.  Now I'm just curious if there's a better way to do this whole query.

Comment: @OllieJones, If you want to post an answer I'll accept it, or if you have anything more to add.  Thanks again for your help.
I also posted the full query, but haven't made a fiddle yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello!**
The solution for that problem is a **SQL Function** called **MIN** and it works like this:

```
SELECT MIN(primary_key_column),the_other_columns FROM table_name;
```

As you can see , at the start of the Query (After the word SELECT) you just Call the function MIN and give the column that also is the Primary Key of the table.
Because this function find the minimum of the registers of the table.I mean that if the selected column is an INTEGER it will be going to find the row with the Smallest Number in that column
If you are using **PHP** too there is a function to make that called **mysql_fetch_array**,for this function you have to make first a quy with another **PHP** function called **mysql_query** and use it like this

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename",$conectionVariable)or die(mysql_error);
```

Then we call the function mysql_fetch_array and store it in a variable like this:

```
$myQueryArray = mysql_getch_array($myQuery)or die(mysql_error());
```

Now for use it you have to call it like a normal Array:

`$myQueryArray['COLUMN_NAME']`
And it return you the value of that column is the first Row

Well,that all.

## Thanks!